# Unnecessary dash in Instagram icon for Font Awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have the following code for the Font Awesome icons in the navbar:

```
<u class="nav-social-media">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>    
 </u>
```

Now I have checked all the pseudo-code in the `:after` and `:before` parts , but I still seem to get this small dash:

[image]

Why am I getting that dash?

I even tried changing the Instagram icon to a image instead of the icon, but still get the dash. Why?

Comment: @FezVrasta i have a reset that does exactly that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your `li` items contained in an `underline` element.

Change that to an `un-ordered list` element instead, and you'll be sorted.

```
<ul class="nav-social-media">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>    
</ul>
```